A function to change a GPS' exported code into viable lines / polygons
One of my older GPS systems records and exports the point type that it measures though a code. For instance: 1111 means it's a line that's part of a polygon belonging to a floor. -1111 would be the start of that floor polygon, 1111 makes up the vertices of it and 1111SR means that's the end of it and that point should be connected to the start. If a new -1111 is started before any "SR" code is provided, it also means the previous line has ended and a new one should be started. 3310 is a height measurement that's recorded just as a point.
Now the export I get is a txt file with a bunch of columns including an id number, X, Y and Z coordinates and then that piece of code. And where I used to have a bit of software that ran in AutoCAD to transform that into lovely lines and polygons, that option is no longer available.
I'm trying to find a function for Qgis (or multiple functions) that would go through that point layer's attributes and process the data so I end up with either attributes that can be used to then use the modeler to create lines (or polygons) that correctly follow the relationships described by the codes.
And I'm having a VERY hard time figuring it out.
Is there anyone that could assist me with this problem?

can you give an example of the 'txt file with a bunch of columns including an id number, X, Y and Z' in your question?
